# iOS GDataXMLElement set element value

Tags: ios, element, gdataxml

I'm using GDataXML in iOS and I'm trying to figure out how to change a node's value (i.e. the content of the equivalent element in the original XML file).  I have an `NSArray` of elements that were returned from an XPath query.  However, I can't seem to find the right function to change or set the value.  I would basically like to do the following:

```
for (GDataXMLElement *element in elementArray) 
{
    [element setValue:myVal];
}
```

But there's no setValue method available for `GDataXMLElement`, nor for `GDataXMLNode`. The closest is `setValue:forKey` as follows:

```
[element setValue:myVal forKey:myKey];
```

But I can't figure out what myKey should be.  When I use `[element name]` I get the error

> "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key [element name]

I'm totally lost, help please!

Comment: What about `setStringValue:myVal`? Did you try?

Comment: Thanks that worked!  How do I give you credit for solving?

Comment: I answered your question. If you want mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `setStringValue:`. So for example:

```
[element setStringValue:myVal];
```

Hope that helps.